# Question about odbc's in c#

Tags: c#, odbc, sybase

I run a c# process and in the middle of the night this happens:

```
ERROR [HY000][DataDirect][ODBC Sybase Wire Protocol driver] Timeout exceeded
```

I know for sure that the database is always active! But this keeps happening! Do you how can I fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
is there a way to put the timeout four times bigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the network connection goes down.

I'd suggest setting up a small IsAlive utility to check this. Either write something small that send out a ping every 30 seconds or so and logs any problems or you might be able to download some tool that does this.

Comment: is there a way to put the timeout three times bigger?

Comment: You can always change the `OdbcConnection.ConnectionTimeout` or you might be able to do it by going to the ODBC control panel applet and changing the settings.

Answer (score 0):

This because Login Trigger is stopping connecting to Database.